# How to set nginx location

Tags: nginx

here is my question

I am learning nginx recently

And I don't know why I can handle my config about location

here is my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;


    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    root /Users/billyliou/web-site;

    location / {
        root html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /demo {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /demo/index.html?s=$uri&$args;
    }

    location /test {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html?s=$uri&$args;
    }
...
```

I put two folders into '/Users/billyliou/web-site'

one is demo , the other is test.

Both contain index.html.

And when I type localhost:8080, it shows nginx default page.
When I type localhost:8080/demo it shows demo page.
but when I type localhost:8080/test , it shows demo page too.
the last one is beyond my expectation.

How can I set this config?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location /demo {
        root    /Users/billyliou/web-site/demo;
        index   index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?s=$uri&$args;
    }

    location /test {
        root    /Users/billyliou/web-site/test;
        index   index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?s=$uri&$args;
    }

    location / {
        root    /Users/billyliou/web-site;
        index   index.html;
    }

    ...
}
```